# How do I save the outputs of a code to a text file for logging (python)

Tags: python

Hello I am really new to programming and im trying to make like some form-like thing where you input stuff and it gets saved to a text file how do I input the outputs of my code to a text file?

```
    date = input("The Date [Month/Day/Year]: ")
print("")
Name = input("Name: ")
print("")
Age = int(input("Age: "))
print("")
Gender = input("Gender: ")
print("")
Nationality = input("Nationality: ")


p = Age + 10

print(p)

print(date, Name, Age, Gender, Nationality)
```

I tried adding

```
sys.stdout = open("test.txt", "w")

(my code here)

sys.stdout.close()
```

I got from google but instead what it did when I run it is leave the console completely blank. I'll appreciate help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default when your program is printing stuff normally, it prints it to a special file named "stdout" (AKA  "standard output", which is your console). The code you got updates stdout to instead reference a file named "test.txt" in write mode (hence the "w"). Therefore, everything you print normally will be rerouted to that new file. There should be a file named "test.txt" in the directory where you are executing your python program, and it should have the output of your program.

Another way of writing to files that I often see is:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
     # your code here
     # the file will save and close after you exit this block scope
     # ex. write:
     file.write('hi')
```

Comment: thanks so much I just used like a y = open('D:/records/text.txt', 'w') and y.write()

now my problem is figuring out how to make it go to a new line so they arent cramped up in the same line for organization, how do I do that? Thanks so much bro!

edit: nvm I found the magic of \n lol thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in which you want to store your information. Collect all your data in a list or dict. I would prefer dict because information is stored systematically. After that, open the file in python in append mode. Remember that your program and your file must be at the exact same location. If not, mention the file location while opening it. I'm recommending append mode because everytime you write, the data should not be lost. If you open in write mode, everytime you write in a file, it writes from starting which may result in losing of data. Now write the dict in the file. Your code:

```
date = input("The Date [Month/Day/Year]: ")
print("")
Name = input("Name: ")
print("")
Age = int(input("Age: "))
print("")
Gender = input("Gender: ")
print("")
Nationality = input("Nationality: ")

p = Age + 10

print(p)
di={"Date":date,"Name":Name,"Age":Age,"Gender":Gender,"Nationality": Nationality}
print(date, Name, Age, Gender, Nationality)
f=open("test.txt","a")
f.write(di)
f.close()
```